# How to suspend a task using FreeRTOS

Tags: rtos, freertos

Am trying to learn freeRTOS. How can I make a task to go to sleep after running for 2 seconds? I've tried  using `vTaskSuspend()` to stop the task immediately and i also  tried to put `v taskDelay(2000)`, but it doesn't work either.

I want to sleep the fast blinking task  2 seconds after it was called  and run the normal blinking task.

```
void resourse(const TickType_t xFrequency)
{
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    while(1)
    {
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin);
    vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, xFrequency);
    }
}
xSemaphoreHandle botton_one = 0;
void botton(void* r)
{

    while(1)
       {
        if(xSemaphoreTake(botton_one, 1))
        {
        HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(B1_GPIO_Port, B1_Pin);
        xSemaphoreGive(botton_one);
        }
        vTaskDelay(1);

       }
}
void normal_blinking(void* r)
{
    while(1)
       {
        if(xSemaphoreTake(botton_one, 1))
        {
            resourse(500);
            xSemaphoreGive(botton_one);
        }

      }
}
void fast_blinking(void* s)
{
    while(1){
        if((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(B1_GPIO_Port, B1_Pin))== 0)
        {
        xSemaphoreTake(botton_one, 1);
        resourse(50);
        xSemaphoreGive(botton_one);
        }
        vTaskDelay(2000);
        vTaskSuspend(NULL);
    }
}

int main(void)
 {
    TaskHandle_t xHandle;
    botton_one = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();

     xTaskCreate(botton, (const char*)"task_1", 1024, 0, 3, 0);
     xTaskCreate(normal_blinking, (const char*)"task_2", 1024, 0, 2,0);
     xTaskCreate(fast_blinking, (const char*)"task_3", 1024, 0, 1,0);

     vTaskStartScheduler();

     while (1){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are wanting to do, or what is not working as you want.  You suggest using both [vTaskSuspend()](http://www.freertos.org/a00130.html) and [vTaskDelay()](http://www.freertos.org/a00127.html), but they are used for different things.

If you call vTaskDelay() then the task will enter the Blocked state (stop being available as a task that can be actually executing) for whatever period you specify, then automatically leave the Blocked state after that period.

If you call vTaskSuspend() then the task will enter the Suspended state, and will never run again unless another task or interrupt calls [vTaskResume()](http://www.freertos.org/a00131.html).

Do you just want the task to run for two seconds, and then never again?  In which case you could do something simple like:

```
void mytask( void *pv )
{
TickType_t xTimeOnEntering = xTaskGetTickCount();

    while( xTaskGetTickCount() - xTimeOnEntering < pdMS_TO_TICKS( 2000 ) )
    {
        /* Run your code here. */
    }

    /* Two seconds of execution is up, delete the task. */
    vTaskDelete( NULL );
}
```

Comment: i need the task to run for two seconds and then go to sleep and start again when its called. this is done by pressing a button.

Comment: Why is there HTML at the end of your code block? Will that compile?